# How can I access to internet in other programs rather than browsers using a wired connection?

Tags: internet-connection

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in my compuer. I am using a Lan connection to have internet (it is like those connections when you have to enter a user name and password), but if i want to use internet in other place like for making updates or using a different program that needs internet, it is impossible. I don't know if it is because of the configuration of the Lan I am using or is my computer. In fact the only browser I can use is Firefox and because I configured something but i don't remember what, I can't use Google Chrome to access internet with this LAN connection. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to buy a router to connect to your internet that can be configured to connect with your username and password. That way, any computers behind the router will not have to authenticate to connect to the internet (except wireless passwords).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. If you go to system settings, then network, then make sure wired is selected on the left, then click on options on the right, you should be able to enter your username, password and any other details. I hope this will be useful.
Oh if you try it, make sure "connect automatically" is checked where you enter your details.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are authenticating through a RADIUS server like we often see in public hotspots.

Try to establish your connexion using Firefox. Then try your other applications. They should work unless a firewall blocks them.